# Change design of website for every user from webpage

Tags: redux, sass, mern

I am currently working on a MERN website and I want to add the ability for the person I am making it for to change some of the design elements on the website. They would have to log in and they would have an extra page where they could change the font, colour, size of the text and maybe the text itself. I thought of storing the values for the changes in mongo and when a user visits the site it would send a request for that data which would change to design for everyone. I would store these values in a state variable or redux (if I end up using it) when they are retrieved. So I was wondering if there is a better way to do this because this would probably end up slowing down the initial load for the website. Obviously I would add a default design incase the db can't be accessed.

Thanks for the responces in advance.

Comment: Possibly use cookies?